# Deserialize XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization

I have an XML file containing 4 different strings, but I am having trouble deserializing the file. Could someone help me with this?

I looked online for answers, but none of them worked, I'm not sure what to do about it.

Here is the XML file I am trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<saveData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<strFolder1>1st Location</strFolder1>
<strFolder2>2nd Location</strFolder2>
<strTabName>newTab0</strTabName>
<strTabText>Main</strTabText>
</saveData>
```

Comment: The XML looks like ... and you want to deserialise it into an object of a class that looks like ...?

Comment: What didn't work?  You are now asking people to repeat the answers you already know.

Comment: You say you're having trouble "deserializing the file". Are you getting an error message or do you have a block of code to look at?

Comment: I never worked with xml files before and i don't know where to start

Comment: I was able to create the file, but I do not know how to deserialize it

Comment: In that case, I doubly emphasise my view that you should learn about XmlReader first. It's often the more involved way, but as is often the case, learning the more-work way first gives you a good idea about it and what the easier ways give you when they apply, while learning the less-involved ways first give you a knowledge of that one approach and a resistance to learning more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8a5e1s5). Some other approaches are easier in different ways, but you can build anything from XmlReader. Such as:

```
while(rdr.Read())
  if(rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    switch(rdr.LocalName)
    {
      case "strFolder1":
        strFolder1 = rdr.ReadContentAsString();
        break;
      case "strFolder2":
        strFolder2 = rdr.ReadContentAsString();
        break;
      case "strTabName":
        strTabName = rdr.ReadContentAsString();
        break;
      case "strTabText":
        strTabText = rdr.ReadContentAsString();
        break;
    }
```

(We could take some short-cuts if guaranteed the ordering, I did it the hard way to show that the hard way isn't that hard).

Using XmlDocument, XmlSerializer and XDocument are easier in a lot of cases, but I recommend learning this first because it'll handle everything and is never less efficient. If you learn it first the worse that'll happen is you do a bit more work than necessary to end up with something a bit more efficient than strictly necessary (you'll do a micro-optimisation out of ignorance of the simpler ways). If you learn the others first the worse that'll happen is you do a lot more work than necessary to end up with something a lot less efficient than needed.

Comment: thank you, and I do like learning things the harder way, because like you said it is often more efficient and it usually gives you a better grasp of what you are actually doing.

Comment: Yeah. I'd like to say that my thirst for knowledge has meant that learning a higher-level approach has never prevented me learning a lower-level the moment I needed to, but I'd be a complete liar if I did! Of course, do learn the other ways too.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(saveData));
var obj = (saveData)ser.Deserialize(stream);

public class saveData
{
    public string strFolder1;
    public string strFolder2;
    public string strTabName;
    public string strTabText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Cars1
{

    public class saveData
    {
        public string strFolder1;

        public string strFolder2;

        public string strTabName;

        public string strTabText;

    }


    [Serializable]
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            saveData obj = new saveData();

            FileStream fopen = new FileStream("abc.xml", FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            StreamReader read_from_xml = new StreamReader(fopen);
            obj = (saveData)x.Deserialize(read_from_xml);

            Console.WriteLine(obj.strFolder1 + "=>" + obj.strFolder2 + "=>" + obj.strTabName+"=>"+obj.strTabText);
            Console.ReadKey();

            fopen.Close();

        }
    }
}
```